# jquery lightbox issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

on http://www.holzschild24.com/schritt1.php i use 
http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/

and i get an error: `$("#slider").easySlider` is not a function

Any ideas, what that can be? All files are laoded correctly, i want that when i click on a pic, i get a big version,...any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are stating comes from the file included on this line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/customSlide.js"></script>
```

Because your jQuery for adding the lightbox comes after that line the javascript has stopped because of the error, so the `.lightBox()` is never added.

See it [**working here**](http://jsfiddle.net/3CRus/) when you remove that line.

Alternatively add the [easy slider](http://cssglobe.com/post/5780/easy-slider-17-numeric-navigation-jquery-slider) plugin if it is actually required:

Added to the [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/3CRus/1/)

---

Also, just so you know, in your comments for the lightbox code, you state you are adding lightbox to anchors `<a...></a>` with lightbox in the `rel` attribute, but you aren't your code is simply adding lightbox to all anchors!!

Due to your current HTML, you could use this as your jQuery, instead of `$('a').lightBox();`

```
$('a').each(function() {
    var obj = $(this);
    if (obj.children('img').size() > 0) {
        obj.lightBox();
    }
});
```

That will go through each anchor, check if the anchor is wrapping an image *`<img..../>`*, only then will it add the `.lightBox()` to the anchor.

See this working [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/3CRus/2/) notice your home link now act as a link, instead of opening a `.lightBox()` like the first examples.

Answer (score 0):

What is easySlider?  I'm only seeing the plugin lightBox

Don't you mean $('#slider').lightBox();